# Cannot connect to certain servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to connect to a certain server, an error message came saying *"Connection refused"* and *"no further information"*. This situation does not appear in other servers.

This situation also does not appear when I connect through another WiFi. It also doesn't appear when I use another address to connect to the server.

The version of Minecraft doesn't matter as this appears in every version. I tried relogging and redownloading Minecraft, but it does not solve the problem.

Is it because of my Firewall settings?
Is it because of the WiFi settings?
Is it because of the server? Which has nothing to do with me?

Comment: What version of Minecraft is the server running?

Comment: It is using 1.8, but my friends can still connect with 1.8.1 and sometimes 1.7.X.

Comment: Connection refused sounds like the server wouldn't let you connect.  Perhaps your IP is blacklisted?

Comment: I did not get banned though.

Comment: If you can connect to other servers without issue, but only this one you can't, especially with that message, then the problem is server side, not on your end.  Perhaps you're using an IP of someone who *did* get banned?  Only real way to find out is to talk to the server administrators.

Comment: Okay. Sounds like I have to contact them then.

Answer (score -2):

**POSSIBILITIES**

**1)** You could be banned from the server, in which case you cannot reach it.

**2)** Firewall: make sure that windows firewall/McAfee/(any other) aren't blocking the internet connection, if so search online on how to unblock an internet connection through that certain program.

**3)** You have a cracked version on minecraft, which can only reach cracked servers (there is no fix for this).

P.S. as far as i know, there it is extremely likely to be your internet connection/WiFi issues, try using a cable to connect to the internet to see if it works then.

Comment: 1: I did not get banned; 2. I have the premium version; 3. Is there any tutorials that you would recommend for the "search online on how to unblock an internet connection through that certain program"?